# Reverting to MBR partition

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I was trying to create a GTP partition table in an SD card using the following command:

```
sudo sgdisk --clear --new=1:2048:67583 --new=2 --typecode=1:3000 --typecode=2:8300 /dev/sdb
```

My problem is that the device I wanted to partition was the `/dev/sdf` instead of the `/dev/sdb` which I used in the command, which also happens to be the partition into which I am currently booted, running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Once the command finished executing it printed a message that the changes would take hold after a reboot or after running partprobe which I did. I am currently backing up my data in case I can not log in after reboot but I would also like to know if there is any chance of reverting back to the old partition table.

I run an `fdisk` both before and after running the `sgdisk` command and here is the partitions of the disk:

**BEFORE**

Disk /dev/sdb: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000AAKX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcd8fe8f7

| Device | Boot | Start | End | Sectors | Size | Id | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/sdb1 | * | 2048 | 1050623 | 1048576 | 512M | ef | EFI (FAT-12/16/32) |
| /dev/sdb2 |  | 1052671 | 976771071 | 975718401 | 465,3G | f | W95 Ext'd (LBA) |
| /dev/sdb5 |  | 1052672 | 976771071 | 975718400 | 465,3G | 83 | Linux |

**AFTER**

Disk /dev/sdb: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000AAKX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcd8fe8f7

| Device | Boot | Start | End | Sectors | Size | Id | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /sdb1 | * | 2048 | 1050623 | 1048576 | 512M | ef | EFI (FAT-12/16/32) |
| /dev/sdb2 |  | 1052670 | 976771071 | 975718402 | 465,3G | 5 | Extended |
| /dev/sdb5 |  | 1052672 | 976771071 | 975718400 | 465,3G | 83 | Linux |

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It shows dos in both cases. "Disklabel type: dos" So no change. Actually if UEFI booting, you should use gpt. And even if BIOS booting can use gpt. The only place MBR(msdos) is required is for BIOS boot of Windows. But if you convert a drive, you change UUIDs & GUIDS, so have to reinstall grub and edit fstab with new UUIDs. Conversion works ok with data only drives, but with boot drives usually better to reinstall. But if using UEFI, you should use gpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After backing up my data I restarted my computer, thinking I would have trouble booting. Turns out that was not the case, and I managed to log in. So indeed, as @oldfred mentioned I was already using GPT, so all the sgdisk command did was to create a new partition on my disk. From the location of the new partition I thought the boot partition would be affected but it turns out it wasn't. It is possible the system recognised a corrupt partition table and used the back up. So it all seems to be working fine. Thank you all.